# What type of connector is this for this motor?

Tags: motor, identification, connector

I'm looking for this connector for this motor: Oriental Motor GFV2G10S.

[image]

[image]

I'm not particularly familiar with these types of motors or their connections. We want to order a cable to fit this but the lead time is 5 weeks and it looks like we could simple make a cable up if we can get this connector. The other side is a simple 6 way MOLEX style connection. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ask the manufacturer, I've asked Oriental motor before and they have given me pinouts and connectors

Comment: Oh wow. Good luck with that one.

Comment: If you take the connector off, could you solder to the wires on the inside? Just until you get a proper cable.

Comment: The question says ``Oriental Motor GFV2G10S``, but looking the the Oriental Motor on-line shop https://catalog.orientalmotor.com/item/egories-shop-online-components-ac-motor-components/gearheads-2/gfv2g10s the GFV2G10S part number is for a _Parallel Shaft Gearhead for use with a wide variety of motors_, rather than the actual motor itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, think the Oriental Motor `GFV2G10S` part number given in the question is actually for [Item # GFV2G10S, GFV Series Parallel Shaft Gearhead (10:1) (Metric Shaft)](https://catalog.orientalmotor.com/item/egories-shop-online-components-ac-motor-components/gearheads-2/gfv2g10s) which is a *Parallel Shaft Gearhead for use with a wide variety of motors* and not the actual motor.

The Oriental Motor website gives [BLM230HP-GFV](https://catalog.orientalmotor.com/item/egories-shop-online-components-ac-motor-components/ponents-pinion-shaft-motors-for-use-with-gearheads/blm230hp-gfv) as the single entry in the list of *Compatible Motors* for the Gearhead.

The BLM230HP-GFV [Brushless Motor Operating Manual](https://www.orientalmotor.com/products/pdfs/opmanuals/HM-5188E.pdf?_gl=1*ha7vgs*_ga*MTAxMDM4NDIwNS4xNzA0NzM0ODkz*_ga_VV8FQHSH1R*MTcwNDczNDg5Mi4xLjEuMTcwNDczNjE2MC4xMS4wLjA.) gives a part number for connector cable assemblies. [Item # CC010HBLF, Connection / Extension Cable (F Type - Motor Shaft Outlet), 1 m](https://catalog.orientalmotor.com/item/all-categories-legacy-products/ategories-legacy-products-accessories-discontinued/cc010hblf) has a picture of the cable end for the motor:

[image]

I can't see the motor connector part number specified in the Oriental Motor documentation, but a reverse image search found Hirose [MT Series Waterproof, Power and Signal Hybrid Connector with Lever for Compact Motors](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/MT) which looks similar:

[image]

The [Series Catalog - English [MT_Catalog_en_MT_Standard_CAT.pdf: 413 KB]](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=MT&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=en_MT_Standard_CAT) has the following end-on picture of the connector which has the same number and layout of contacts as the that shown on the motor in the question, albeit on the motor not all contacts as populated:

[image]

Perhaps the connector on the motor can be measured to see if it matches the dimensions given for the Hirose MT series to confirm if a match.

Comment: Nice detective work. Assembly instructions [here](https://www.hirose.com/medias/ETAD-E3191-01_0001548755.pdf?context=bWFzdGVyfHByaXZhdGVfc3lzX3VwbG9hZHw1NDI3OTN8YXBwbGljYXRpb24vcGRmfGMzbHpMVzFoYzNSbGNpOXdjbWwyWVhSbFgzTjVjMTkxY0d4dllXUXZhRGt5TDJnd05pODVNek15T1RFME1EazBNVEV3TDBWVVFVUXRSVE14T1RFdE1ERmZNREF3TVRVME9EYzFOUzV3WkdZfDg3ZDExYjhlMWI3MWU3ZjYwOTBlMjYyOGRlMjQ0OWU2Zjc2MmE0ODk1OTBlODI1YjgzNDUzNTI5MzBiMDg0MTQ). It probably wants a $1000 USD+ crimping tool.

Comment: as @Spehro Pefhany says, good detective work!